# Direct passage from $n$ prime to $n$ non-prime in Euler Totient Function $\Phi$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, totient-function

I wish to derive, for a proof, the Euler Totient Function starting from the case $n$ prime to $n$ non-prime.

Let $n$ prime, we know $\Phi(n)=n-1$. But what if now I assume $n=p_0^{a_0}p_1^{a_1}...p_r^{a_r}$ and I want to reach $\Phi(n)=n \prod_{p|n}^{}(1-1/p) $ from there?  Like:

$\Phi(p_0^{a_0}p_1^{a_1}...p_r^{a_r})=p_0^{a_0}p_1^{a_1}...p_r^{a_r}-1 \Rightarrow p_0^{a_0}p_1^{a_1}...p_r^{a_r}(1-1/(p_0^{a_0}p_1^{a_1}...p_r^{a_r}))=?$

Is this kind of approach possible for this formula?

Comment: The two steps are $\phi(p^k) = p^k-p^{k-1}$ and $\phi(nm) = \phi(n) \phi(m)$ whenever $gcd(n,m)=1$ thus $\phi(n) = \prod_{p^k \|n} \phi(p^k) = n\prod_{p^k \|n} \frac{\phi(p^k) }{p^k}= n \prod_{p| n} (1-p^{-1})$

Comment: In particular, it is not true that $\phi(p_0^{a_0}p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_r^{a_r})=p_0^{a_0}p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_r^{a_r}-1$ when $p_0^{a_0}p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_r^{a_r}$ is not prime.

Comment: So such kind of derivation, as I suppose, it's not possible. Thanks

Comment: @reuns the symbol "$||$" means for "that divide"?

Comment: $p^k\| n$ iff $p^k | n$ and $p^{k+1} \nmid n$. In this setting $p$ means (ranging over) the primes and $p^k$ means over the prime powers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be precise, your "kind" of derivation is not possible. This is because  $\phi(p_0^{a_0}p_1^{a_1}...p_r^{a_r})\neq p_0^{a_0}p_1^{a_1}...p_r^{a_r}-1$.

Think about what the totient function entails: the number of integers less than the input that are coprime with it. Only with prime inputs is this one less than the input.

The totient function, however, does retain two properties, namely as reuns mentioned, that $\phi(p^k)=p^k-p^{k-1}$ and $\phi(n)\phi(m)=\phi(mn)$ when $m$ and $n$ are coprime. The proof of these is easily verifiable given a google search.

Thus, we can have a "direct" approach. Since powers of primes are always coprime to one another, 
\begin{align*}
\phi(n)&=\phi(p_0^{a_0}p_1^{a_1}...p_r^{a_r})\\
&=\phi(p_0^{a_0})\phi(p_1^{a_1})...\phi(p_r^{a_r})\\
&=(p_0^{a_0}-p_0^{a_0-1})(p_1^{a_1}-p_1^{a_1-1})...(p_r^{a_r}-p_r^{a_r-1})\\
&=p_0^{a_0}(1-1/p_0)p_1^{a_1}(1-1/p_1)...p_r^{a_r}(1-1/p_r)\\
&=n\displaystyle\prod_{p|n}(1-1/p).
\end{align*}